# Module Loader loading the same Library multiple times

Tags: javascript, requirejs, modularization

I'd like to separate my page into two independent "decoupled" areas.

Now let's assume that both need the same dependency with the same version.

Is requireJS or any other library capable of managing different lifecycles of different libraries? Allowing next-to "real" decoupling in JavaScript?

I don't want to load the stuff globally as different version of the same could be loaded eventually.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by " managing different lifecycles of different libraries? Allowing next-to "real" decoupling in JavaScript?"